# imapsync some mails are not transferred

Tags: email, imapsync

Im using this code:

```
imapsync --buffersize 8192000 --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldate --noauthmd5 
--host1 old.server --user1 old.user --password1 123456 
--host2 localhost --user2 user@domain.com --password2 123456
```

Result is:

```
Initial difference host2 - host1  : -1559 messages, -258705799 bytes (-246.721 MiB)
Final   difference host2 - host1  : -6 messages, 34513 bytes (33.704 KiB)
Detected 0 errors
```

**So 6 messages are not transferred. What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Missing messages can be duplicates on host1. See whole final statistics.